# How can I create a list of UI elements, each aligned differently?

Tags: reactjs

Say I want to create a list of UI elements, and I want each element to align differently. I was imagining something like:

```
<List>
<Button Alignment="right"/>
<Panel Alignment="left"/>
<Video Alignment="center"/>
</List>
```

How is this best achievable? Preferably by not adding special handling of the alignment property to each child element.

Comment: You didn't attach the image and some of the basic attempts you've made. This also doesn't sound like a React issue specifically?

Comment: Ah didn't catch that. The question is in relation to react, specifically. Coming from angular, in that world I would likely create an 'alignment' directive that would set some properties. I was just wondering what the equivalent would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to accomplish something like that in React, with no particular way necessarily being the "best."

I'd definitely recommend looking at:

http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html

Here's one idea using a simple mixin.

```
var List = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button alignment="right" />
                <Panel alignment="left" />
                <Video alignment="center" />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Button = React.createClass({
    mixins: [AlignmentMixin],
    render: function() {
        return (            
            <Button  { ... this.props } className={ this.renderAlignment() } />
        );
    }
});

var AlignmentMixin = {
    renderAlignment: {
        // whatever you'd like, just an example
        // of constructing a class name called box-right/left/center
        return "box-" + this.props.alignment;
    }
}
```

There isn't an equivalent to an Angular directive that could be applied globally to all types. React takes a different approach and by design (currently) expects that components present a well-known interface and cannot be arbitrarily extended by the consumer of the component. It means that a component in ReactJS is only what it says it is and can do, and a parent component can only affect its behavior by setting properties on the component instance.

In the example I provided above, I've explicitly added the "alignment" mixin to the Button. Without it, the button would not have the feature of alignment.

Of course, you could just add the necessary code to the Button to do the alignment if there wasn't a general pattern that could be applied as simply as I have shown above.

Some might not even use a mixin as they would rather have the code that "is a" `Button` be only in a file called, `Button.js` (for example). The UI and behavior is not spread around multiple files potentially as it might be in an angular app (where directives may be in different files and difficult to discover what might be applied to any given element).

In fact, from the "[why react page](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/why-react.html)":

> Since they're so encapsulated, components make code reuse, testing,
>   and separation of concerns easy.

Comment: Thank you. I think this answers it pretty well.